# Using a large database in Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

I'd like to write an Android application which will function as a dictionary (glossary). Therefore, I need a pretty big database (I assume about 200 thousand entries).

As I am pretty new to Android programming, I have no idea how to hold such a big database. I thought the interface should be a `ListView` with all entries, and a search option. Furthermore I thought about holding the database itself in a file to be stored on SD card.

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: Some quick math says 200k entries at 100 chars each is about 20 meg - that seems to me more than people would want to put on their data plan and phone, but that's just my take. Perhaps consider making it a webservice (with caching) so they don't have to take it all?

Comment: That's not really a problem for me because I intend to let the user download the file on their desktop computer and transfer it to their SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses SQLite so as far as I am aware you can create the *.sqlite file (and even rename it if you want) with any external tool you may use (maybe server) and once you have it have a look at [`android.database.sqlite`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

As to connecting the date to a ListView you can use an [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) along with a [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or the easier to implement [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)

For searching here is a quite complete guide of how to implement it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

or you can have a look at this android example that implements both sqlite and search:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Hope it helps!